# Appending values in dictionary using for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, append

```
dic={}
l=[]
for i in range(0,2):
    c=input("Enter your name").strip()

    for i in range(0,3):
        d=int(input("Enter Your marks: "))
        l.append(d)
    dic[c]=l



print(dic)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
{'alex': [36, 54, 78, 57, 78, 94], 'harry': [36, 54, 78, 57, 78, 94]}
```

Expected Output:

```
{'alex': [36, 54, 78], 'harry': [57, 78, 94]}
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are always appending to the **same** list instead of a separate one for each student.

Comment: `l = []` inside first loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options. Either redefine `l` as an empty list *within* your outer `for` loop, so that the same list is not appended to throughout. Or use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to append to a default list value. Here's an example of the second option:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(2):
    c = input("Enter your name").strip()
    for i in range(3):
        dic[c].append(int(input("Enter Your marks: ")))
```

Using a `defaultdict` is more efficient and arguably more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Lists in python are [mutable objects](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/), which mean that the `l` variable always points to the same list object. You could easily fix that by doing:

```
dic={}
for i in range(0,2):
    l=[]
    c=input("Enter your name").strip()

    #(...)
```

That way, a new list object is instantiated at each iteration.

> NB: you could simplify your code by using [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
dic={}
for i in range(2):
    c = input("Enter your name").strip()
    l = [int(input("Enter Your marks: ")) for _ in range(3)]     
    dic[c]=l
```